# Certificate format conversion is implemented under wolfssl

Tags: c, x509

Here is the conversion function I used:

```c
int convertDERtoPEM(const char* derFilePath, const char* pemFolderPath) {
    FILE* derFile = fopen(derFilePath, "rb");
    if (!derFile) {
        printf("Error opening DER file %s\n", derFilePath);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char* derData = NULL;
    fseek(derFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long derSize = ftell(derFile);
    rewind(derFile);
    derData = (unsigned char*)malloc(derSize);

    if (!derData) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        fclose(derFile);
        return -1;
    }

    fread(derData, 1, derSize, derFile);
    fclose(derFile);
    WOLFSSL_X509* x509 = wolfSSL_X509_new();
    if (!x509) {
        printf("Error creating X509 structure\n");
        free(derData);
        return -1;
    }

    if (wolfSSL_d2i_X509(&x509, &derData, derSize) == NULL) {
        printf("Error converting DER to X509\n");
        free(derData);
        wolfSSL_X509_free(x509);
        return -1;
    }
    
    const char* baseName = basename(derFilePath);
    char pemFileName[256];
    snprintf(pemFileName, sizeof(pemFileName), "%s/C_%.*s.pem", pemFolderPath, (int)(strlen(baseName) - 4), baseName);
    FILE* pemFile = fopen(pemFileName, "wb");
    
    if (!pemFile) {
        printf("Error opening PEM file %s for writing\n", pemFileName);
        free(derData);
        wolfSSL_X509_free(x509);
        return -1;
    }

    if (wolfSSL_PEM_write_X509(pemFile, x509) == 0) {
        printf("Error writing PEM certificate to %s\n", pemFileName);
        fclose(pemFile);
        wolfSSL_X509_free(x509);
        free(derData);
        return -1;
    }
      
    fclose(pemFile);
    wolfSSL_X509_free(x509);
    free(derData);
    printf("Conversion complete. %s converted to PEM and saved as %s.\n", derFilePath, pemFileName);
    return 0;
}
```

When this function is executed in batches, it keeps encountering segmentation faults. The message is as follows:

```
#0  0x00007ffff78a54c9 in arena_for_chunk (ptr=0x55555556317a)
    at ./malloc/arena.c:156
#1  arena_for_chunk (ptr=0x55555556317a) at ./malloc/arena.c:160
#2  __GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3390
#3  0x0000555555555782 in convertDERtoPEM (
    derFilePath=0x7fffffffde90 "./der/rights.1688.com_1.der", 
    pemFolderPath=0x555555556121 "./pem_c") at DtoP.c:71
#4  0x00005555555558b2 in main () at DtoP.c:89
```

When I commented out the last free, I was able to complete some conversions but reported an error on a specific certificate.

```
Conversion complete. ./der/rights.1688.com_1.der converted to PEM and saved as ./pem_c/C_rights.1688.com_1.pem.
Conversion complete. ./der/alibaba-ipmarket.tmall.com_1.der converted to PEM and saved as ./pem_c/C_alibaba-ipmarket.tmall.com_1.pem.
Conversion complete. ./der/xinyong.1688.com_1.der converted to PEM and saved as ./pem_c/C_xinyong.1688.com_1.pem.
Conversion complete. ./der/movie.jd.com_1.der converted to PEM and saved as ./pem_c/C_movie.jd.com_1.pem.
Conversion complete. ./der/hao123-static.cdn.bcebos.com_1.der converted to PEM and saved as ./pem_c/C_hao123-static.cdn.bcebos.com_1.pem.
Error writing PEM certificate to ./pem_c/C_gys.1688.com_1.pem
segfault
```

However, according to the function content, only if is satisfied before the function is free, then -1 is also returned to end the function. Why does the stack information still report an error at the last free point? If I don't comment the last free the whole execution is directly:

```
liu@liu-VirtualBox:~/test$ ./DtoP
segfault
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and format your question, it is barely readable currently. While you're [edit]ing your question, add what you tried to debug the issue.

Comment: Never mind, I formatted it.

Comment: You're corrupting your heap, either by overrunning a buffer or making an invalid `free()` or `realloc()` call with a pointer that was already freed or has a value that wasn't returned from `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc.